# FormControl valueChanges not firing

Tags: angular6

What might be wrong with this code? I can't see that `valueChanges` is getting fired.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tagsSubscription = this.service.tags$.subscribe(...);
    this.createForm();
    this.service.getSupportedTags(new TagId('sometag')); 
    this.languageSelectorForm.get('tagsFilterCtrl').valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log("received value chnage from filter control ");// I don't see the print and the mat-select object's value is `object Object`
        this.filterTags();
      });
  }


createForm() {
    this.languageSelectorForm = this.fb.group({
      tags: [null, Validators.required],
      tagsFilterCtrl:[null] //filter input shows here
    });
  }
```

The filter control is being used as

```
<div id="mat-select-div">
          <mat-select id="language-selector" placeholder="Tags" class="selectpicker" formControlName="tags" [ngClass]="validateField(languageSelectorForm,'tags')" #singleSelect>

            <mat-option *ngIf="newSearch">Please select</mat-option> 
            <mat-option>
              <ngx-mat-select-search formControlName="tagsFilterCtrl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">{{tag.subject}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with `valuechanges`. There was some other logic error. However, it is strange that I don't see the print in the `valueChanges` observable.